# Java DTO and final fields

Tags: java, pojo, dto, final

There is question about DTO (Data Transfer Object) and java implementation with final modifier to fields.

In fact. All DTOs must be created in one place (constructor) without any logic inside DTO. If there are several sources - there is aggregation-service, which can collect all data and put it into new DTO. Also DTO with final fields will be more predictable. Isn't it?

Example:

```
 @Getter
 class FooDto {
   private final ... fooField;
 }
```

The question is: should I use final modifier on DTO's fields?
I didn't find information exactly for DTOs. But in my opinion - final is good point here.

Comment: Sure, if you want to. You can make everything `final`...until you realize you need to reassign them. However are you sure `final` is enough? What about immutable objects?

Comment: Why should I reassign DTO fields? It is just DTO without any logic. POJO to transfer data with some format into another systems.

Comment: Will that work if the DTO is used for incoming data where the values may be set by a framework?

Comment: You can use immutable entities nowadays with most frameworks. As long as you have a constructor containing all available fields. You may have to add some annotations on the constructor depending on the framework though.

Comment: I didn't say you *should*. But the `final` modifier is unlikely to make a large effect on the quality of the code. In most cases the flow of the code should guarantee that there wouldn't be any reassignment happening by accident anyway, and if someone does it intentionally, you can't prevent that from happening (they can always remove the `final` modifier). So it's up to you, but it doesn't make a significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

There is no correct and wrong answer for your question. Although, it is good practice to use final fields like mentioned [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=23)

If you have no further control on your fields before return statement then you're good to go with final fields. You should consider "**Immutable Object Design Pattern**" as a good practice for that.

If somehow you need to make a second check before you return your object then you can remove the final modifier and use a library for mapping and avoid extra code. You can use [Mapstruct](https://mapstruct.org/)